# Embedded PostScript in python strings. Need help preserving special characters

Tags: python, utf-8

I am trying to create a python module that contains snippets of PostScript and Embedded PostScript that I can use to construct print jobs. The strings of embedded PostScript contain ^M's at the end of lines that I need to preserve when writing to stdout.

At the top of my module I have:

```
# coding=UTF-8
```

and declare the strings of eps data as triple quoted strings like this:

```
eps_snippet =
"""
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0^M
/pdfmark where {pop true} {false} ifelse^M
/currentdistillerparams where {pop currentdistillerparams^M
"""
```

(when pasting the snippet into this web form it stripped out the ^M's so I added the characters "^" and "M" myself for illustration)

When I try to print this string to stdout the ^M's at the end of lines are lost.

I have tried the following ways of printing:

```
print eps_snippet
sys.stdout.write(eps_snippet)
```

Please help!

Comment: Have you tried using `\r`?

Comment: I have not. Could you please be more specific? How would I use it in this example?

Comment: Instead of having the interpreter optimize out your CRs that it thinks are part of the NL, spell them out.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. This did what I was asking. Just to spell it out, in vim I did :%s/<ctrl-v><ctrl-m>/\\r/   It turns out I was asking the wrong question. My problem is that the encapsulated postscript that I am trying to put into a string switches from ASCII to binary and back.